# Not able to get ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest() method in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I am writing a Windows Phone 7.5 application for Background agent. I am adding the code

```
ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest( 
                periodicTaskName, 
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 20 ) );
```

method, but for this method it is showing me the error

> Error Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.ScheduledActionService' does not contain a definition for 'LaunchForTest'

For reference I have checked definition which is not having 'LaunchForTest' method. If anyone knows how to get that please reply.

```
public sealed class ScheduledActionService
{
    // Summary:
    //     Registers a scheduled action with the operating system.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   action:
    //     The Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.ScheduledAction to be registered.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   InvalidOperationException:
    //     A scheduled action with the same Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.ScheduledAction.Name
    //     property is already registered with the system.
    public static void Add(ScheduledAction action);
    //
    //
    // Returns:
    //     Returns Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.ScheduledAction.
    public static ScheduledAction Find(string name);
    //
    //
    // Type parameters:
    //   T:
    //
    // Returns:
    //     Returns System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetActions<T>() where T : ScheduledAction;
    public static void Remove(string name);
    public static void Replace(ScheduledAction action);
    }
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the project targets Windows Phone 7.1 (on the Application tab of the project properties)?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you have an older version of the SDK installed? A beta perhaps?

Verify that the Microsoft.Phone assemby is version 7.0.0.0 and file version 3.0.30701.2350.

You can run through this How-Do-I video that showcases the ScheduleActionService to verify you have the right bits, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh369939.